# Check file type photo / video / text reactjs

Tags: javascript

How can I check if file that uploaded is a photo / video / text ?
I want to put different icon by the file type that uploaded..

code:

```
<input type="file" name="addNewFile" id="newFile"
                        onChange={(e)=> setFile(e.target.value)}/>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Check the mimetype? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type

Answer (score 0):

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)

#### Getting information on selected files

Getting information on selected files
The selected files' are returned by the element's HTMLInputElement.files property, which is a FileList object containing a list of File objects. The FileList behaves like an array, so you can check its length property to get the number of selected files.

Each File object contains the following information:

- name
- lastModified
  -size
- **type** ::

> The file's [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types).